# Use memcache From Other Server

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, memcached, port

I have one Ubuntu Based memcache server.

Now i want my new server to use old server's memcache.

**What i tried ?**

Opening tcp port in my firewall 11211

But still i am unable to use it.

In /etc/memcached.conf:

```
# Specify which IP address to listen on. The default is to listen on all IP addresses
# This parameter is one of the only security measures that memcached has, so make sure
# it's listening on a firewalled interface.
-l 127.0.0.1
```

I have changed 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0/0

Sudo Ip Tablet output

```
[sudo] password for azureuser:
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Listening on 0.0.0.0 should do it.  Can you try telnetting to the port from the new machine.  What does `sudo iptables -L` output?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be for the listening server?

Comment: okay i edited question. Now it includes output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret your question as you wanting your localhost to use another machines memcached instance.

If this is indeed the case then you should just have to replace the `127.0.0.1` with the other machines IP, e.g. `192.168.1.111`

Comment: My other Machine have dynamic ip.How  Can i allow all ips ?

Comment: What you're asking for sounds impossible. Maybe it's just my interpretation though. Maybe use DNS and a hostname if the IP is dynamic or switch to static

Comment: Actually it's azure website. I am configuring it to utilize my old memcache server. Azure Site Url is like xxx.azurewebsites.net/ . I don't know how to configure my server to allow memcache request.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. sorry.

Comment: Opening up memcached to the world at large is incredibly dangerous. Don't do it. http://www.slideshare.net/sensepost/cache-on-delivery